# How to stop Http Request with responseType: stream?

Tags: node.js, axios, cancellation, node-streams

So I use Axios to fetch stream data from external API.

I tried to use AbortController to cancel the request when needed. But it didn't stop the stream. So I assumed that Abort Controller can cancel Http Request but stream still happens.

So I tried to use Readable.destroy() to stop the stream.

I'm thinking that Should I just only use Readable.destroy() the stream and the HTTP request will be cancelled together. Or I need to use Abort for Http Request and also destroy stream.